# Calling one list from a multi-list variable: Why isn't the print statements inside if statements not printing?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to create a function that produces the finalized grades. This function should multiply the course grades by the course bonus, so the first course list ([55,21,30,58,49]) should be multiplied by 1.0 and so on, and the same thing is done to the exam grades but with the exam bonus instead. Then it multiplies the adjusted exam and course grades together to give the total grade. The print statements inside of the if statements are not printing, I've already looked through similar questions about print() not working, but nothing seemed relevant.

NOTE: I cannot change the main program

```
def finalized_grades(course_grades, exam_grades, course_exam_bonus, exam_bonus):
    adj_course = []
    adj_exam = []
    total = []
    print('Before update:')
    print('Coursework = {}'.format(course_grades))
    print('Exams = {}'.format(course_grades))
    print('Course Bonus = {},'.format(course_exam_bonus),end=' ')
    print('Exam Bonus = {}'.format(exam_bonus))
    print('After update:')
    for c in course_grades:
        if c == [0]:
            adj_course = [x*course_exam_bonus[0] for x in course_grades[c]]
            print('Coursework = {}'.format(adj_course))
        if c == [1]:
            adj_course = [x*course_exam_bonus[1] for x in course_grades[c]]
            print('Coursework = {}'.format(adj_course))
        if c == [2]:
            adj_course = [x*course_exam_bonus[2] for x in course_grades[c]]
            print('Coursework = {}'.format(adj_course))
    for e in exam_grades:
        if e == [0]:
            adj_exam = [x*exam_bonus[0] for x in exam_grades[e]]
            print('Exams = {}'.format(adj_exam))
        if e == [1]:
            adj_exam = [x*exam_bonus[1] for x in exam_grades[e]]
            print('Exams = {}'.format(adj_exam))
        if e == [2]:
            adj_exam = [x*exam_bonus[2] for x in exam_grades[e]]
            print('Exams = {}'.format(adj_exam))
    for t in range(len(adj_course)):
        total = [adj_exam[t]*adj_course[t]]
        print('Total = {}'.format(total))
    return

################################# MAIN PROGRAM #################################### 
def test_finalized_grades():
    course_grades = [[55,21,30,58,49], [47,39,29], [43,32,28,60]]
    exam_grades = [[35,14, 32,18,31] , [32,32,19], [15,21,24,39]]
    course_exam_bonus = [1.0,1.25,1.2]
    exam_bonus = [3.0,0.0,2.0]
    for i in range(len(exam_bonus)):
        grades = finalized_grades(course_grades[i],exam_grades[i],course_exam_bonus[i],exam_bonus[i])
    return
```

This is what my output looks like

```
Before update:
Coursework = [55, 21, 30, 58, 49]
Exams = [55, 21, 30, 58, 49]
Scale = 1.0, Bonus = 3.0
After update:
Before update:
Coursework = [47, 39, 29]
Exams = [47, 39, 29]
Scale = 1.25, Bonus = 0.0
After update:
Before update:
Coursework = [43, 32, 28, 60]
Exams = [43, 32, 28, 60]
Scale = 1.2, Bonus = 2.0
After update:
```

There should be statements in-between 'Before update' and 'After update'. This is what it should look like.

```
Before update:
Coursework = [55, 21, 30, 58, 49]
Exams = [35, 14, 32, 18, 31]
Scale = 1.0, Bonus = 3.0
After update:
Coursework = [55.0, 21.0, 30.0, 58.0, 49.0]
Exams = [38.0, 17.0, 35.0, 21.0, 34.0]
Total = [93.0, 38.0, 65.0, 79.0, 83.0]
```

Comment: `adj_exam[t]` is not correct. `t` is an element of `adj_exam`, not an index.

Comment: Obviously, your `if` conditions are never True. Why don’t you a) make the second and subsequent `if` statements into `elif` (because the conditions are exclusive), and b) then add an `else:` which prints e.g. the value of `c` or `e` which din’t match the previous conditions.

Comment: `finalized_grades()` doesn't return anything, why are you assigning the result to `grades`?

Comment: It's not `print`, it's that your `if` never matches

Comment: Why are you comparing with a list like this: `if c == [0]:`? `c` is a number, not a list.

Comment: Change all the tests like `if c == [0]:` to `if c == 0:`

Comment: @Barmar I was told c == [0] would mean that if c is the first list from course_grades then the following is applied to it.

Comment: No, it's testing if `c` is a list containing a single zero.

Comment: **Then it multiplies the adjusted exam and course grades together to give the total grade.** Your sample output has them added together, not multipled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you program gets to

```
for c in course_grades:
```

then `course_grades` is `[55, 21, 30, 58, 49]` in the first call to finalized_grades, so your `c` ist 55, then 21, then 30, etc.

It is never [0], [1] or [2]

`finalized_grades` is always called with only one of the lists of your list of lists:

```
for i in range(len(exam_bonus)):
    grades = finalized_grades(course_grades[i],exam_grades[i],course_exam_bonus[i],exam_bonus[i])
```

As you can see, the correct exam bonus is already passed as an argument, so you don't need to check for the first, second or third element.

It should be something like this:

```
for c in course_grades:
    adj_course = [x*course_exam_bonus for x in course_grades[c]]
        print('Coursework = {}'.format(adj_course))
```

But I also see that your stated output doesn't match your code. Where is this output?

> Course Bonus = ...

Answer (score 0):

You're making this way more complicated than it needs to be.

You shouldn't be using list comprehensions inside the `for` loops. You just need a single list comprehension for each adjustment.

You don't need to compare with an index into `course_exam_bonus` or `exam_bonus`. It's just a single number in the function, the indexing was done in `test_finalize_grades()`.

Use `zip()` to iterate over both adjusted lists together to add them together.

```
def finalized_grades(course_grades, exam_grades, course_exam_bonus, exam_bonus):
    print('Before update:')
    print('Coursework = {}'.format(course_grades))
    print('Exams = {}'.format(course_grades))
    print('Course Bonus = {},'.format(course_exam_bonus),end=' ')
    print('Exam Bonus = {}'.format(exam_bonus))

    adj_course = [c * course_exam_bonus for c in course_grades]
    adj_exam = [e * exam_bonus for e in exam_grades]
    total = [c + e for c, e in zip(adj_course, adj_exam)]

    print('After update:')
    print('Coursework = {}'.format(adj_course))
    print('Exams = {}'.format(adj_exam)
    print('Total = {}'.format(total))

    return total
```